# Filter nested JSON object using JSONPath with Condition

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a below json object and need to get only c_Internet child object with a condition where the PIID is having value "1234567".

```
{
  "OrderComponentInfo": {
    "members": {
      "ADD": {
        "DIA": [
          {
            "c_Internet": {
              "PIID": "1234567",
              "IPv6_Multiple_Path_Needed": ""
            },
            "Test": {
              "PIID": "1234567",
              "INT_Acc_MSP_ID": "",
              "ConnectedService": "INTERNET"
            }
          },
          {
             "c_Internet": {
              "PIID": "7658964",
              "IPv6_Multiple_Path_Needed": ""
            },
            "Test": {
              "PIID": "7658964",
              "INT_Acc_MSP_ID": "",
              "ConnectedService": "INTERNET"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I trued below query but dint work

```
$..ADD.DIA[?(@.PIID = "1234567")][['c_Internet']]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use c_Internet.PIID not just PIID

```
const id="1234567";

$..ADD.DIA[?( @.c_Internet.PIID == id )]["c_Internet"]
```

result

```
[
  {
    "PIID": "1234567",
    "IPv6_Multiple_Path_Needed": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: How can I pass value "1234567" in variable ?
this is not working 
$..ADD.DIA[?(@.c_Internet.PIID == Id )]["c_Internet"]